How to properly use cockroachdb/errors
I am using Go and stumbled over cockroachdb/errors for error handling. I understand that errors.Wrap can be used to add more context and stack traces to errors, like this:
func DoSomething() error {
    err := os.WriteFile(...)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "something happened here in DoSomething")
    }
}

func CallSomething() error {
    err := DoSomething()
    if err != nil {
        return errors.WithDetail(err, "here is some additional info")
    }
}

Assuming, that the usage above is correct, I am not sure how to handle errors from third-party libraries. Consider the following:
func DoSomething() error {
    err := some.ThirdPartyLibraryCode(...)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "something happened here in DoSomething")
    }
}

If the third-party library also uses cockroachdb/errors, wrapping their errors with errors.Wrap might result in nested errors with multiple stack traces, which could produce confusing output:
(1) attached stack trace
  -- stack trace:
  | graph-editor/nodes.(*Graph).ExecuteImpl
  |     /Users/daniel/git/graph-main/start@v1.go:52
  | [...repeated from below...]   ??
Wraps: (2) failed to execute  

How should I handle errors from third-party libraries that might already be using cockroachdb/errors (or not) to avoid duplicated stack traces and keep the error output clear?

According to the documentation, creating an error with the New() family offers this options of printing related information:
// - message via `Error()` and formatting using `%v`/`%s`/`%q`.
// - everything when formatting with `%+v`.
// - stack trace and message via `errors.GetSafeDetails()`.
// - stack trace and message in Sentry reports.

You're not telling us how you're printing the infos you find confusing. After playing around a bit with the library, I guess, you're using the + prefix for the v verb, e.g. with
fmt.Printf("%+v", myCockroachDBErr)

(Honestly, I don't know why it results in an output like the one you're posting, since according to the fmt documentation this just "adds field names". Go magixx.)
So, with %+v you're opting for "everything" output, which is probabably rarely what you want (apart from debug sessions). You will see more or less all information the error struct holds, in a more or less comprehensable way.
If you just want the straight-forward stack being printed, use
fmt.Printf("%v", errors.GetSafeDetails(myCockroachDBErr))

That said, it seems like Wrap() functions behave rather similar to the New() functions. That means, Wrap() creates a new error, and stores the wrapped one for further reference. While - according to the Wrap() docs - it "retains" the old error'sstack, it's apparently not considered part of the the new error's stack, which starts right where Wrap() is invoked.
If you want to ouput the stack of the wrapped error, you have to unwrap it first:
import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/cockroachdb/errors"
)

func main() {
    wrappingErr := someFkt1()
    fmt.Printf("wrappingErr: %v\n", errors.GetSafeDetails(wrappingErr))
    unwrappedErr := errors.UnwrapOnce(errors.UnwrapOnce(wrappingErr)
    fmt.Printf("got2: %v\n", errors.GetSafeDetails(unwrappedErr))
    return
}


func someFkt1() error {
    return someFkt2()
}
func someFkt2() error {
    return errors.Wrapf(someFkt3(), "outer error")
}

func someFkt3() error {
    return errors.New("inner error")
}

For a better understanding, you can also output "everything" again:
fmt.Printf("everything: %+v\n\n", err)

Which will log smth like:
everything: inner error
(1) attached stack trace
  -- stack trace:
  | main.someFkt2
  |     /myPath/main.go:31
  | [...repeated from below...]  i.e. /myPath/main.go:28, /myPath/main.go:11, proc.go:267, asm_amd64.s:1650
Wraps: (2) attached stack trace  the one we unwrap in my example
  -- stack trace:
  | main.someFkt3
  |     /myPath/main.go:35
  | main.someFkt2
  |     /myPath/main.go:31
  | main.someFkt1
  |     /myPath/main.go:28
  | main.cockroachDBErrors
  |     /myPath/main.go:11
  | runtime.main
  |     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:267
  | runtime.goexit
  |     /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1650
Wraps: (3) inner error  looks like even New() counts as wrapping
Error types: (1) *withstack.withStack (2) *withstack.withStack (3) *errutil.leafError  a helpful legend

I figure you could create a loop unwrapping errors just before you've reached the inmost one, and output that error's stack trace to see it all from the start. I don't see a more straightforward way, though - errors.UnwrapAll() returns the the leafError, which doesn't bear a trace itself.

That was a perfect summary, super helpful! Much appreciated!

First, you have to understand that cockroachdb/errors is really old, it was designed before the extended error handling in Go 1.13 landed. See also “Error Values: Frequently Asked Questions”.
cockroachdb/errors delivers some features (personally identifiable information and sentry.io reporting) which might be important to you, although I think they shouldn't be in a errors package and I also don't like the dependency on gogo/protobuf, but that might be just me.
Another thing that it does is not treat errors like data, but as exceptions. I've wrote a simple sample program to test the usefulness of that:
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"

    cerr "github.com/cockroachdb/errors"
    "golang.org/x/sync/errgroup"
)

func main() {
    err1 := func1()
    fmt.Printf("func1: %+v, expected: %v\n", err1, errors.Is(err1, ErrOne))

    err2 := func3()
    fmt.Printf("func3: %+v, expected: %v\n", err2, errors.Is(err2, ErrTwo))
}

func func1() error {
    var g errgroup.Group

    g.Go(func2)

    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("func1 failed: %w", err)
    }

    return nil
}

var ErrOne = errors.New("error one")

func func2() error {
    return ErrOne
}

func func3() error {
    var g errgroup.Group

    g.Go(func4)

    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        return cerr.Wrap(err, "func3 failed")
    }

    return nil
}

var ErrTwo = cerr.New("error two")

func func4() error {
    return ErrTwo
}

Unfortunately it doesn't compile on the Go Playground, timing out due to the dependencies cockroachdb/errors pulls in. When I run it locally I get:
func1: func1 failed: error one, expected: true

for the first call, which is expected: I define an ErrOne, signifying some error and enrich that at returning from func1. You don't have to use the function name for that, something that is easily findable with a text search should suffice. This gives me an idea where the error has occurred, I would also add parameters so that I could understand which call caused that error. Also, I check programmatically whether I get ErrOne.
The second line is:
func3: func3 failed: error two
(1) attached stack trace
  -- stack trace:
  | main.func3
  |     [...]/main.go:43
  | main.main
  |     [...]/main.go:15
  | [...repeated from below...]
Wraps: (2) func3 failed
Wraps: (3) attached stack trace
  -- stack trace:
  | main.init
  |     [...]/main.go:49
  | runtime.doInit1
  |     [...]/go/src/runtime/proc.go:7176
  | runtime.doInit
  |     [...]/go/src/runtime/proc.go:7143
  | runtime.main
  |     [...]/go/src/runtime/proc.go:253
  | runtime.goexit
  |     [...]/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1695
Wraps: (4) error two
Error types: (1) *withstack.withStack (2) *errutil.withPrefix (3) *withstack.withStack (4) *errutil.leafError, expected: true

which - I don't know, lots of stuff is not even written by me - it's package initialization code. Also, the stack traces are disjoint, because I use a predefined error definition (to be able to test for it, and also not waste resources creating the same error over and over again) and goroutines, which should not be uncommon in Go programs.
Are you sure sending data to sentry.io and treating errors as exceptions is worth it? If yes, I assume multiple stack traces should be fine, since you can not know whether the original error came from your stack or a different goroutine. Stack traces have been popularized by languages with a mostly linear stack and missing opportunites to efficiently enrich error messages.
If you are searching for more powerful debugging techniques, may I suggest looking into flight-recording instead?

Super helpful, much appreciated! Especially that the package is older than some of the Go error handling, that explains a few blog posts that I couldn't wrap my head around

@HelloWorld Yes, the changes that landed in Go 1.13 were initially planned for Go 2, so that's what old posts refer to as “Go 2 error handling”.
